# RxJS How to Wait For Two ReplaySubjects To Produce Values Before Continuing

Tags: rxjs, observable

I want to use for join like this:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.service1.dataSourceIsAReplaySubject,
    this.service2.dataSourceIsAnObservable)
.subscribe(values => {
    console.log('inside subscribe values is', values);
});
```

but the console.log never fires.

I'm guessing the replay subject never completes which is why forkJoin never stops waiting.

I've tried this, but this doesn't work either.
I've tried the ReplaySubject first and the Observable second and vice versa.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    Observable.from(this.service1.dataSourceIsAReplaySubject),
    this.service2.dataSourceIsAnObservable)
.subscribe(values => {
    console.log('inside subscribe values is', values);
});
```

I also tried calling the share method:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.service1.dataSourceIsAReplaySubject.share(),
    this.service2.dataSourceIsAnObservable)
.subscribe(values => {
    console.log('inside subscribe values is', values);
});
```

What can I do to wait on either two ReplaySubjects or a mix of 1 ReplaySubject and 1 Observable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`forkJoin` won't emit a value until the observables passed to it complete; it emits the *last* values of each of those observables.

You can ensure they complete by using the `first` operator:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.service1.dataSourceIsAReplaySubject.first(),
    this.service2.dataSourceIsAnObservable.first())
.subscribe(values => {
    console.log('inside subscribe values is', values);
});
```

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'before continuing'? `forkJoin` emits the last values and then completes, so I'm not sure what 'continuing' means here.

Comment: The ui depends on two flags produced by each observable. Initially both are unknown, so the ui is blank. It's not safe to Aquire these flags in separate subscriptions since the ui may flash if the first observable produces true and the 2nd observable produces true a moment later. The ui will have these transitions: unknown+unknown, true+unknown then true+true. Therefore forkjoin is perfect in this scenario because both flags get set once both observable have produced a value.

Comment: I know this is 6 years later but.

@IanT8 By only getting the first value you are making your UI non-responsive. It will never respond to changes in the ReplaySubject or any other observables, it will only operate on the first one. `forkJoin` quite possibly the wrong operator to use.

`combineLatest` waits for all observables to emit before it does so itself, so you won't get the "unknown" transitions - your first hit will be `true+true`. But it also continues watching those observables in case they change.

Answer (score 10):

As you yourself noted, the problem is that `forkJoin` only emits once all streams complete. If you were going to use it you would need to make sure that all of your streams complete in some fashion (`first()`, `take(1)`, etc...).

A better option though might be to use either `zip` or `combineLatest` depending on your needs. The implementation would look similar:

```
Observable.zip(
    this.service1.dataSourceIsAReplaySubject,
    this.service2.dataSourceIsAnObservable
).subscribe(values => {
    console.log('inside subscribe values is', values);
});

// OR

Observable.combineLatest(
    this.service1.dataSourceIsAReplaySubject,
    this.service2.dataSourceIsAnObservable
).subscribe(values => {
    console.log('inside subscribe values is', values);
});
```

**Breakdown**

[`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) will emit the two Observables in lock step with each other, that is each time one emits, the other must also emit before zip will emit a value, while this is useful it can also be dangerous if one emits much more rapidly than the other (since it will cause an unbounded buffer to grow behind the scenes).

[`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) will wait until both streams have emitted *at least once* and then any time one emits, `combineLatest` will emit with the latest of the other stream.

There is also a third option, called [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom). It functions similar to `combineLatest` with the caveat that it only emits when the *first* stream emits and silently updates all the other latest values without emitting.